# grep not recognizing parenthesis

Tags: r

I have a column in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
STATUTE
961.41(1)(A)
961.41(1)(B)
961.41(1)(A)
961.41(1)(A)
961.41(1)(C)
```

I'm trying to use GREP to identify any record in "STATUTE" column that contains the string '961.41(1)(A)' and make a description in a new column if that string is found:

```
my_data$STATUTE_DESCR[grepl('961.41(1)(A)',my_data$STATUTE, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES"
```

Desired output:

```
STATUTE           STATUTE_DESCR
961.41(1)(A)      DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES
961.41(1)(B)
961.41(1)(A)      DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES
961.41(1)(A)      DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES
961.41(1)(A)4     DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES
961.41(1)(A)(B)   DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES
961.41(1)(C)
```

But, the grep statement is not working with the parenthesis.  Can anyone advise?

Comment: you need `fixed = TRUE` and not `ignore.case` ie `my_data$STATUTE_DESCR[grepl('961.41(1)(A)',my_data$STATUTE, fixed = TRUE)] <- "DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES"`

Comment: `grepl('961\\.41\\(\\d+\\)\\(A\\)', '961.41(1)(A)')
[1] TRUE`, escapting (for more generalized cases), but fixed=TRUE here, as above.

Answer (score -1):

You have to scape the metacharacter `(` using `\\`. Use `'961.41\\(1\\)\\(A\\)'` as regex or set `fixed = TRUE` inside `grepl`

```
> my_data$STATUTE_DESCR[grepl('961.41\\(1\\)\\(A\\)',my_data$STATUTE, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES"
> my_data
       STATUTE                       STATUTE_DESCR
2 961.41(1)(A) DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES
3 961.41(1)(B)                                <NA>
4 961.41(1)(A) DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES
5 961.41(1)(A) DELIVER/MANUF CONTROLLED SUBSTANCES
6 961.41(1)(C)                                <NA>
>
```